# Location simulation using Instruments and UI Automation script on real device

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, automation, instruments

I am testing my iOs app on real device (iPhone 5s, iOs 8.4) using Instruments (Version 6.4 (6E35b)) tool - UI Automation scripts to simulate location. If I use script on simulator everything works like a charm. My script is something like:

```
var target = UIATarget.localTarget();

// speed is in meters/sec
var points = [
          {location:{latitude:49.272930000,longitude:16.574600000}, options:{speed:15, altitude:200, horizontalAccuracy:10, verticalAccuracy:15}},
          {location:{latitude:49.272060000,longitude:16.575000000}, options:{speed:27, altitude:200, horizontalAccuracy:10, verticalAccuracy:15}}]
for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++)
{
    target.setLocationWithOptions(points[i].location,points[i].options);
    target.delay(0.3);
}
```

Please note I have enabled UI scripts and other scripts work on device eg.

```
target.setDeviceOrientation(UIA_DEVICE_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPELEFT);
```

works fine. Did I forget something or is it a bug?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: No, I am not aware of any possible way. Here (https://medium.com/bpxl-craft/simulating-locations-with-xcode-revisited-2e1b1c13c3bc#.p63cb2ftr) is good article showing possible ways of simulating location.